# Get a unique re-useable identifier of node (cli-)app what is running in different terminal windows in parallel by same user?

Tags: node.js, process, terminal, pid, tty

I like to get an **unique reusable identifier of the terminal window** my node app (a CLI) is running in. The reason I like to know this is **the common use of the app by the same user within multiple terminals at the same time.**

It is necessary to get back selected data for each terminal and also getting to know what is selected on different terminal windows the CLI-App is running in.

**The best way to save this would be in a hidden log file basically named by a unique terminal identifier.**

[x] Working on `process.platform === 'win32'` each `cmd.exe` has its own PID.

[ ] Working on `process.platform === 'darwin'` (Mac OS X) the PPID is the same on all terminal windows.

[ ] Working on `process.platform === 'freebsd' || 'linux' || 'sunos'` I assume it is the same problem also depending on the GUI you are running.

**Executing `tty` on the terminal gives me different identifiers like `/dev/ttys003` what would be useful.**

But trying to get this out of the app is not possible because executing this within a child_process ends up in a `not a tty`!

The PID of the app itself is changing every time it is executed. Thats not helpful in this case. The parent PID is the same (but also in different terminals).

Setting env will not be bound to the terminal but only to the apps runtime.

Is there any idea to get this done ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself:

[SpoTTY](https://github.com/keybase/node-spotty) is the solution for posix based systems.

The example on the page has a misleading bug - use this example to get it done:

```
// A clone of the `tty` command
var spotty = require('spotty');
var tty = spotty.tty(function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error found: " + err.toString())
    } else {
        return res;
    }
})
```

hope this helps someone.